# Why some HTML5 tags must have a starting and ending tag instead of self closing them with />?

Tags: html

In HTML5 there are tags that must have a starting and an ending tag even when their content is empty:

```
<script></script>   <!-- Right way. -->
<div></div>         <!-- Right way. -->
<content></content> <!-- Right way. -->

<script/>  <!-- Wrong way. -->
<div/>     <!-- Wrong way. -->
<content/> <!-- Wrong way. -->
```

In XML this difference doesn't exist:
`<node/>` and `<node></node>` are the same entity.

Why tags like `script`, `div` and `content` can't be defined simply as:
`<script/>`, `<div/>` and `<content/>`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why don't self-closing script tags work?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/69913/1529630).

Comment: Script tags can be self closing if you have a valid src defined.  The other two are containers that should have inner elements.  If not, there is probably a better element to use instead (ie img instead of div with background-image).

Comment: @AdamMilecki `script` elements can't be self-closed, even if they have a `src`, because they aren't void elements.

Comment: Collecting pieces from other answers, HTML tags are divided in `void` and `not void` tags. Even if in XML `<node/>` and `<node></node>` are the same thing, in HTML5 the self-closing form is reserved to *void* tags.

Comment: Interesting answer from [Are self-closing tags valid in HTML5?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3558200/1750243).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[From the w3c](http://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/#self-closing-tag):

> A Self-closing tag is a special form of start tag with a slash
>   immediately before the closing right angle bracket. These indicate
>   that the element is to be closed immediately, and has no content.
>   Where this syntax is permitted and used, the end tag must be omitted.
>   In HTML, the use of this syntax is restricted to void elements and
>   foreign elements. If it is used for other elements, it is treated as a
>   start tag. In XHTML, it is possible for any element to use this
>   syntax. But note that it is only conforming for elements with content
>   models that permit them to be empty.

The examples you listed would generally contain content, JavaScript, or other elements, so having a proper start and end tag would delimit the scope of those elements/tags.

Comment: Your quote explains everything. Thanks for the authoritative source.

Answer (score 2):

Simply because they are basically some "container" for other elements.

There are elements which are didn't used as parent elements for others, like img or base for example, this one can be closed without an closing tag with a trailing />, but it is not necessary.

Answer (score 1):

These (void elements) may be terminated with `/>`

`area, base, br, col, embed, hr, img, input, keygen, link, menuitem, meta, param, source, track, wbr`

However its optional and irrelevant:

> This character has no effect on void elements

MathML/SVG tags may terminate with `/>` to indicate a self closing tag.

([HTML5 Ref](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-author-view/syntax.html#syntax-start-tag))

Comment: Thanks, so only for that **void** tags.

Answer (score 0):

In the HTML5 specifications, some tags are declared as "self closing", and some tags are not.

The `script` tag is special for that. When a browser request a javascript file (given in the `src` attribute of the tag), it will copy the javascript file content in the `script` tag. And if you self close the tag, the browser can't copy any content in the tag so the javascript will not be executed.

Since a few years now, HTML (and especially with HTML5) try to get away from XML "borders". That's why we have attributes boolean values (like `disabled` or `checked`).

Comment: The `checked` attribute appears in HTML 2.0, which pre-dates XML entirely.

Answer (score -1):

```
<script></script>   <!-- Right way. -->
<div></div>         <!-- Right way. -->
<content></content> <!-- Right way. -->
```

In all 3 of those cases, there is an indefinite amount of content that could reside within the tag.

With something like:

```
<input type="text" velue="Hello" />
<img src="image.jpg" />
```

There is no more content that you could possibly add to these.  So you can simply close the tags at the same point that they are generated.

So, it's not a matter of "right or wrong".  It's a matter of what the tag is actually used for.